# Locking without hardware support

Tags: synchronization, locking

I think most locking techniques assumes or makes use of hardware support for atomic transactions. I remember reading about some locking/synchronization algorithms which doesn't need such support, but can't really recall them (token-based or something). Do they exist? If so can I get some links please?

Thanks
Jeenu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check under section named Software Solutions in this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) link.